# web page performance testing in Internet Explorer

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

How can I get the web page load speed and data amount in Internet Explorer? I know about PageSpeed and Firebug for Firefox, is there an equivalent of those tools for IE?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) for testing page performance in IE6+. It's a free download (although you have to create an account to actually get a download link) and hooks in to the browser to get low-level timings of network, rendering, scripting, and other metrics.

It can also show you *what* is taking the largest amount of time.

This tool has been invaluable to me since the site I work on requires IE6 support and performance is critical.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug can be very handy most of the times in Firefox. IE also has this kind of simple application that helps you edit or see the codes in a webpage. Try hitting **F12** to see it.

Comment: Which versions of IE have this? I want to see how long it took to load the resources of the page and which resources were loaded.